# laravel 5 show is returning empty query and not showing any data

Tags: laravel, controller, routes

i am new to laravel and i work on  eloquent i want to send some data to view and show them like laravel documentation says so in my controller i wrote

```
public function show(PhoneBook $phoneBook)
{
    return view('admin.phonebook.show',compact('phoneBook',$phoneBook));
}
```

and in the phonebook show view i wrote

```
 <strong>id</strong> {{ $phoneBook->id }}<br>
 <strong>calldate</strong> {{ $phoneBook->calldate }}<br>
 <strong>description</strong> {{ $phoneBook->description }}
```

any idea why i receive empty query with no result with no errors and just the titles with no result in front of them i thank you if you can help me with this

Comment: You need to give us your table content and structure, and the URL your accessing in order to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controller:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $phonebook = Phonebook::find($id);
    return view('admin.phonebook.show',compact('phonebook'));
}
```

Blade:

```
<strong>id</strong> {{ $phonebook->id }}<br>
<strong>calldate</strong> {{ $phonebook->calldate }}<br>
<strong>description</strong> {{ $phonebook->description }}
```

Comment: thanks you bas or Boss :) it did the job for me but i had another model Task which was working with the same code any idea what was the problem or which way is better to do it ? i was writing that code from this link and toturial

Comment: https://www.5balloons.info/tutorial-simple-crud-operations-in-laravel-5-5/

Comment: i want to know if you way is more standard to do it or this links way :) thanks in advance

Comment: From that tutorial: "*Resource controller uses the Route model binding, This means that you dont need to fetch the specified task by the id. Laravel will do it for you.*" There is no right or wrong. This answer is clear but requires more code. The tutorial contains a bit of magic but requires less code. Pick one, but be consistent!

Comment: thanks You @loek i think the toturial one is better for me but i just wonder why my code is not working its the same as it was in toturial for Task its working but for phonebook no :)

Comment: @user3357687, if want to know why your code is not working, check this link https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/18167

Comment: @user3357687 Change your username ;) Follow courses laracast.com or www.udemy.com, you pay i little, I did and learned a lot. Also you can google, you know how that works ;)

Comment: @bas Yes boss :) i would go for it  :) and i will post what was the problem when ever i find any solotion for it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
 return view('admin.phonebook.show', compact('phoneBook'));
```

Comment: Now you can access on blade template with $phoneBook

Comment: This is the correct answer for the code you provided, so something else is going on.

Comment: Can you please print $phoneBook output?

Comment: You should do, like this:-

public function show($id)
{
$phoneBook = YourModel::find($id);

    return view('admin.phonebook.show',compact('phoneBook'));
}

Anyway.

Comment: App\PhoneBook Object ( [fillable:protected] => Array ( [0] => description [1] => calldate [2] => rememberdate [3] => client_id ) [connection:protected] => [table:protected] => [primaryKey:protected] => id [keyType:protected] => int [incrementing] => 1 [with:protected] => Array ( ) [withCount:protected] => Array ( ) [perPage:protected] => 15 [exists] => [wasRecentlyCreated] => [attributes:protected] =>

Comment: Array ( ) [original:protected] => Array ( ) [changes:protected] => Array ( ) [casts:protected] => Array ( ) [dates:protected] => Array ( ) [dateFormat:protected] => [appends:protected] => Array ( ) [dispatchesEvents:protected] => Array ( ) [observables:protected] => Array ( ) [relations:protected] => Array ( ) [touches:protected] => Array ( ) [timestamps] => 1 [hidden:protected] => Array ( ) [visible:protected] => Array ( ) [guarded:protected] => Array ( [0] => * ) )

Comment: You're getting wrong output. Try with Fetch phoneBook data with id value

Answer (score 1):

You can try 2 ways below to send data from Controller to View:

```
return view('admin.phonebook.show', compact('phoneBook'));
```

OR

```
return view('admin.phonebook.show')->with('phoneBook', $phoneBook);
```

Comment: may i please ask you to tell me what is the diffrence betwen  compact('phoneBook') and compact('phoneBook', $phoneBook)

Comment: you are maybe mistake.
If you use **compact**: you need only `compact('phoneBook')`
OR If you use **with**: you must use `->with('phoneBook', $phoneBook)`